# Feature extraction from AlexNet fc7 layer in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I have this AlexNet model in MATLAB:

```
net = alexnet;
layers = net.Layers;
layers(end-2) = fullyConnectedLayer(numClasses);
layers(end) = classificationLayer;
```

I'm using it to learn features from sequencies of frames from videos of different classes. So i need to extract learned features from the 'fc7' layer of this model to save these features as a vector and pass it to an LSTM layer.
The training process of this model for transfer learning its ok, all right.

I divided my data set in a x_train and a x_test sets using splitEachLabel() in my imageDatastore(), and using the function augmentedImageSource() to resize all the images for the network. Everything ok!

But when i try yo use this snippet of code shown bellow to resize images from my imageDatastore to be readed by the function activations(), to save the features as a vector, i'm getting an error:

```
imageSize = [227 227 3];
auimds = augmentedImageSource(imageSize, imds, 'ColorPreprocessing', 'gray2rgb');
```

Function activations:

```
layer = 'fc7';
fclayer = activations(mynet, auimds, layer,'OutputAs','columns');
```

The error:

```
Error using SeriesNetwork>iDataDispatcher (line 1113)
For an image input layer, the input data for predict must be a single image, a 4D array of images, or an imageDatastore with the correct size.

Error in SeriesNetwork/activations (line 791)
            dispatcher = iDataDispatcher( X, miniBatchSize, precision, ...
```

Someone help me, please!
Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the input size of that layer? The error you are getting is related with the input size of the current layer. Can you check your mynet structure and its fc7 layer input's size in your workspace in Matlab?